# Calculating lag features of mean of pandas column for previous 3 month, 6 month, 1 year and 2 years for this column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

Hello I have a pandas dataframe with month (int), year(int), product_id(string), city_id(string), customer_id(string) and sales(int) and I want to groupby first by specific customer_product_city_month_year combination and get for all the combinations the mean of sales column for the previous 3 months, 6 months, 1 year and 2 years as new column in pandas dataframe

I would appreciate any feedback
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a bunch of data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
dti = pd.date_range("2017-1-1", "2020-12-1", freq="MS")
products = ["cities{}".format(c) for c in range(1, 4)]
cities = ["cities{}".format(c) for c in range(1, 3)]
customers = ["customer{}".format(c) for c in range(1, 5)]

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dti.month, dti.year, products, cities, customers],
                                 names=["month", "year", "product_id", "city_id", "customer_id"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"sales": np.random.randint(0, 30, size=len(idx))}, index=idx).reset_index()
```

```
>>> df
       month  year product_id  city_id customer_id  sales
0          1  2017  products1  cities1   customer1     20
1          1  2017  products1  cities1   customer2     28
2          1  2017  products1  cities1   customer3      5
3          1  2017  products1  cities1   customer4     17
4          1  2017  products1  cities2   customer1     16
...      ...   ...        ...      ...         ...    ...
55291     12  2020  products3  cities1   customer4      6
55292     12  2020  products3  cities2   customer1      1
55293     12  2020  products3  cities2   customer2     21
55294     12  2020  products3  cities2   customer3     16
55295     12  2020  products3  cities2   customer4      3
```

Convert (year, month) to datetime. It's easier to use date manipulation
after:

```
df2 = df.assign(datetime=pd.to_datetime(df["year"].astype(str) + df["month"].astype(str), format="%Y%m"))
df2 = df2.drop(columns=["month", "year"]).set_index("datetime").sort_index()

cols = ["product_id", "city_id", "customer_id"]
out = []
for month in [3, 6, 12, 24]:
    start = df2.index.max() - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=month)
    out.append(df2[start:].groupby(cols).mean().squeeze().rename("{}M".format(month)))
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.concat(out, axis="columns")
                                       3M         6M        12M        24M
product_id city_id customer_id
products1  cities1 customer1    15.161458  14.779762  14.788462  14.433333
                   customer2    14.479167  14.580357  14.706731  14.761667
                   customer3    13.666667  13.738095  14.229167  14.680000
                   customer4    14.828125  14.875000  14.641026  14.539167
           cities2 customer1    14.723958  14.211310  14.161859  14.440000
                   customer2    14.791667  15.083333  14.907051  14.781667
                   customer3    15.015625  14.273810  14.605769  14.664167
                   customer4    14.036458  14.505952  14.358974  14.267500
products2  cities1 customer1    13.666667  13.755952  14.166667  14.179167
                   customer2    13.484375  14.375000  14.025641  14.277500
                   customer3    13.645833  14.119048  14.307692  14.296667
                   customer4    13.244792  13.657738  14.112179  14.137500
           cities2 customer1    13.682292  14.541667  14.434295  14.366667
                   customer2    13.979167  14.116071  14.304487  14.592500
                   customer3    16.489583  15.744048  14.828526  14.671667
                   customer4    14.625000  14.505952  14.099359  14.409167
products3  cities1 customer1    13.562500  14.125000  14.149038  14.221667
                   customer2    14.713542  14.717262  14.520833  14.060833
                   customer3    14.562500  14.696429  14.560897  14.596667
                   customer4    14.536458  14.651786  14.314103  14.075833
           cities2 customer1    14.130208  14.559524  14.089744  14.365000
                   customer2    14.276042  14.279762  14.352564  14.273333
                   customer3    13.901042  14.657738  14.641026  14.254167
                   customer4    14.411458  14.303571  14.258013  14.265000
```

Comment: how I can keep the datetime index in the dataframe after groupby and concat?

Answer (score 0):

i get an error because I have also a week variable so my dataframe is a bit different:

```
       month  year product_id  city_id customer_id  sales
0          1  2017  products1  cities1   customer1     20
1          2  2017  products1  cities1   customer1     28
2          3  2017  products1  cities1   customer1      5
3          2  2017  products1  cities2   customer2     28
4          1  2017  products1  cities3   customer3      5
```

the error im getting is TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '3M' was passed any feedback would be great thanks